# Cloudinary direct unsigned upload with django

Tags: django, image, python-3.x, cloudinary

I am using the cloudinary sample django project:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample

I made the following changes:
- using django 1.8.6 
- using cloudinary 1.4.0
- added CLOUDINARY_URL environment variable
- added cloudinary_cors.html file (provided by cloudinary) in static/html directory

I can perform server-side upload and everything works fine.

When I perform browser upload (signed or unsigned), the image selected uploads to my cloudinary account successfully, but the cloudinarydone event never occurs and the browser doesn't resister a successful upload.

Instead, I am getting this error in the browser console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/[namespace]/auto/upload. The request was redirected to 'localhost:8000/static/html/cloudinary_cors.html?bytes=4304&created_a…s=%23%3CSet%3A0x0000000ab0e050%3E&type=upload&version=[num]&width=402', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

I would think the POST doesn't require a preflight CORS request. I have seen other posts online about the preflight error, and it seems some of them were resolved by fixing javascript imports. My order is:
1. jQuery
2. uiwidget
3. iframe-transport
4. fileUpload
5. cloudinary.js

which seems correct based on said posts.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change to get the cloudinarydone event?

Answer (score 0):

we're working on a fix for this issue.

Meantime, in [upload.html](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample/blob/master/photo_album/templates/upload.html#L73) you should replace the following line:

```
.fileupload({
```

with

```
.cloudinary_fileupload({
```

This should solve the issue for you.